# JAVA - The hardware architecture can affect the generation of a sequence of random numbers?

Tags: java

I have developed a simulation platform (**JAVA**) for the ***motion of thousands of particles in a bounded tridimensional space***.
The simplest motion rule is given by the Brownian motion that is determined by a random gaussian distribution with zero mean and standard deviation that depends on some constant factors for the considered scenario.

The expected result for a punctiform emission of the particles, is a sort of cloud of particles that diffuses along all directions uniformly, with the barycentre of the cloud centered on the initial emission point.

I have performed several simulations on several machines and I have obtained strange results on two specific machines, while the simulations results given by the other machines follows the expected values.

More in detail, it seems that the cloud of particles **is propagating along a preferential direction.**

---

### Maybe the generation of the random coordinates is polarized in some way? It may depend from the hardware architecture of the CPU?

---

The architecture of the computers is:

## Type 1:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- RAM: 32GB

## Type 2:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2300 CPU @ 2.80GHz
- RAM: from 8GB to 24GB

## Type 3:

- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5410  @ 2.33GHz
- RAM: 24GB

Type 1 and 2 give good results, **type 3 gives the wrong results**.

The operating system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The JVM version is: OpenJDK 1.7 (64-Bit)

Comment: How are you generating random numbers? You should be able to reproduce the exact same results on each machine by using the same seed for your random number generator. Are you using threads, you might want to test with a single thread so remove any race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

well, yeah it is. the architecture will have an impact on how the random number will be generated.

Assuming the way you get the random number is like this.

```
new Random().nextInt()
```

Then in the initializer of the `Random` object. it will try to generate the seed that will be used to create the next "random" number. And the way the API generate the seed is by calculating with the current "static" seed and also increment by current nano time.

And to get the current nano time. The JVM will use QueryPerformanceCounter(QPC) which implemented in different ways depending on the hardware it's running on.

For further reference, you could read this awesome [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) by david holmes

Comment: To assure reproducibility you need to specify the seed using `Random(long)`. Also if you want exact portability of a floating-point calculation you should use `strictfp` though it may affect performance and.or precision on some architectures (including Intel).

Comment: To my knowledge a Random object with the same seed with generate the same sequence regardless of the platform it is run on. Your example demonstrates improper use of Random objects.

Comment: @matt Hmmm. Can you explain it more thoroughly why do you thing my example is improper?

Comment: @kucing_terbang I don't think your example is improper, it is a good example. I think it shows an _improper use_ of the Random class exactly for the reason you state. The number generated is relying on the randomness of the seed because a new instance is being created each time. The PRG should be seeded and used obtain a sequence of numbers. Then Java's PRG will be consist across platforms, as documented.

Comment: @matt aaa I see, sorry, my mistake :D

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers.

I have executed several test on each architecture and it would seem that the problem is not on the generation of random numbers.

I have collected a very long sequence of random generated numbers for several days and I have compared them by Matlab script.

The collected results show a polarization of the coordinates along the **x axis**.

I have decided to change the order of generation  of these coordinates from **x,y,z** to **y,z,x** and the results show the same polarization along the **y axis**!

This means that the first generated value is affected by this polarization, but I don't know why.

In addiction, the polarization effect increase as the total amount of created objects (more objects means more coordinates, and so more calls to the custom random method).

Here is the relevant code. The **move()** method is invoked for each timestep for each object throught a multithreaded approach (not shown here):

```
public void move(MyObj p) {
        float[] center=p.getCenter();                   
        float sigma2=getDiffusionCoefficient(p);        

        float dx=getGauss(sigma2);
        float dy=getGauss(sigma2);
        float dz=getGauss(sigma2);

        center[0]=center[0]+dx;
        center[1]=center[1]+dy;
        center[2]=center[2]+dz;
        p.setCenter(center[0],center[1],center[2]); 
    }


// A better implementation of Gaussian Random Number
    public float getGauss(float sigma){
        float rai=(float) Math.sqrt(-2*sigma*sigma*Math.log(1-(random.next(val)/div)));
        float teta=(float) (2*Math.PI*(random.next(val)/div));
        return (float) (rai*Math.cos(teta));
    }
```

Where "*random*" is a **XORShiftRandom** object:

```
// XORShiftRandom
    int val=31;
    double div=Math.pow(2, val);
    XORShiftRandom random=new XORShiftRandom(); 
    // End XORShiftRandom


public class XORShiftRandom {

    private long seed = System.nanoTime();        

    public XORShiftRandom() {

    }    

    protected int next(int nbits) {         
        long x = this.seed;
        x ^= (x << 21);
        x ^= (x >>> 35);
        x ^= (x << 4);
        this.seed = x;
        x &= ((1L << nbits) -1);
        return  (int)(x);
    }
}
```